# Canvas перекрывает activity_main.Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-canvas

Всем доброго времени суток.Недавно начал писать на kotlin в android studio.И у меня встал вопрос.У меня есть код,который рисует движущийся круг на Canvas.И есть activity_main.И canvas перекрывает этот самый activity.И вопрос в том,чтобы они оба рисовались вместе,не перекрывая друг друга.Пробовал делать canvas прозрачным ,но не помогало.Код прилагается.Заранее спасибо.
Вот, что я перепробовал:
Пытался менять цвет  view на 0x0000FF00 в init.
Пытался менять цвет canvas  на 0x0000FF00 в onDraw.
Пытался менять цвет canvas  на 0,255,255,255 в onDraw с помощью ARGB.

'''

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.view.SurfaceView

class copy : View {
    private var mPaint: Paint? = null
    private var mPath: Path? = null
    private var mBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private var mPathMeasure: PathMeasure? = null
    private var mMatrix: Matrix? = null
    private var mOffsetX = 0
    private var mOffsetY = 0
    private var mPathLength = 0f
    private var mStep // distance each step
            = 0f
    private var mDistance // distance moved
            = 0f
    private lateinit var mPosition: FloatArray
    private lateinit var mTan: FloatArray

    constructor(context: Context?) : super(context) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs) {
        init()
    }

    constructor(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        this.alpha
        mPaint = Paint()
        mPaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
        mPaint!!.color = Color.WHITE
        mPaint!!.strokeWidth = 3f
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources,
                R.drawable.lol)
        mOffsetX = 20
        mOffsetY =20
        mPath = Path()
        mPath!!.moveTo(50f, 50f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(150f, 50f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(150f, 100f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(250f, 100f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(250f, 150f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(350f, 150f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(350f, 200f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(450f, 200f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(450f, 250f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(50f, 250f)
        mPath!!.lineTo(50f, 50f)
        mPathMeasure = PathMeasure(mPath, false)
        mPathLength = mPathMeasure!!.length
        mStep = 1f
        mDistance = 0f
        mPosition = FloatArray(2)
        mTan = FloatArray(2)
        mMatrix = Matrix()
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mDistance < mPathLength) {
            mPathMeasure!!.getPosTan(mDistance, mPosition, mTan)
            mMatrix!!.reset()
            val degrees = (Math.atan2(mTan[1].toDouble(), mTan[0].toDouble()) * 180.0 / Math.PI).toFloat()
            mMatrix!!.postRotate(degrees, mOffsetX.toFloat(), mOffsetY.toFloat())
            mMatrix!!.postTranslate(mPosition[0] - mOffsetX, mPosition[1] - mOffsetY)
            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap!!, mMatrix!!, null)
            mDistance += mStep
        } else {
            mDistance = 0f
        }
        invalidate()
    }
}
'''
```

Comment: По идее всё и так должно работать как вы описываете.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я решил отредактировать вопрос, добавив то, что Я уже перепробовал.

Comment: Всё ещё не ясно в чём у вас проблема. У вас не устанавливается цвет фона где-то?

Comment: Нет, дело в том, что изначально у canvas цвет фона - белый. И когда я запускаю проект, то у меня отображается сам canvas, а вот activity_main (на котором у меня написан текст) перекрывается им. И в итоге этот самый текст не виден, а мне бы хотелось, чтобы отображалось и то, и другое.

Comment: А как вы пытались цвет View менять? Вы меняли цвет фона на прозрачный? И это не сработало?

Comment: Пытался:this. setBackgroundColor(0х0000FF00)  в init.Не сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему созданием отдельного activity для нее